# Device Browse using Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, bluetooth

I had been using Bluetooth device browse using my system (Dell Inspiron 1525) and my mobile (Nokia 6233) in Ubuntu 10.04. Yesterday I installed 11.10. Bluetooth, send file option, detecting devices, etc. all are working properly, but the browse option isn't. The application is not crashing or anything, but nothing happens when you click the browse option.

I tried running `blueman-browse` from the terminal, but then I got an error that `Could not parse arguments: Unknown option --browser`.

When I checked the `nautilus` man page, it had a `--browser` option, but when I tried running `nautilus --browser` from the terminal the same errors as above itself was coming. As the browse device option usually opens the mobile filesystem in `nautilus`, I thought that this missing `--browse` option might be the reason for this issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you use backports, then just purge package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.1-oneiric-generic

```
sudo aptitude remove linux-backports-modules-cw-3.1-oneiric-generic
```

and reinstall kernel

```
aptitude reinstall linux-image-generic
```

Now reboot.
It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution from here:

http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/1767/a-bluetooth-quick-fix-hack-for-ubuntu-11-10/

It works fine for me..